# how to include facebook page in a website

Tags: php, html

am trying to include my facepage into my website so if i entered url www.whatever.com

it shows the facepage

i tried

`iframe` html 
`include /include_path /file_get_contents` in php but it's no use

i know that facebook not supporting the iframe anymore but there's should be a way to include my facepage inside my website.

i don't need a like button or anything like that i want to include the page it's self!

so is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

How does Facebook not support `iframe`?  Maybe they don't support using an `iframe` when creating a Facebook page internal to the site, but it sounds like you just want to include it in an `iframe` from your own site, external to Facebook.  [That seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Wyyjp/).

You can just add an `iframe` to your page and set its `src` to the intended Facebook page.  Style it a little better, of course.  (Mine is just styled to emphasize the existence of the `iframe`, you'd generally want to style it to hide its existence so it fits well with the surrounding page.)  But you can reference a Facebook page in an `iframe` just fine.  No PHP code is necessary.

Comment: try this page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/PoP-Demons/107900662608692  you will find it not working , and thats what am talking about!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  It looks like Facebook has a script which actively detects `iframe`s and redirects.  More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352759/how-to-embed-a-facebook-page-in-an-iframe  From the looks of things, Facebook explicitly disallows this practice, in which case so far there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.  I'm sure they have a Terms Of Service somewhere that forbids it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook scripts don't allow parents, meaning that they don't want their site viewed through an iframe. If there is a way around this, its going to be a longshot.

Comment: This is outdated, see my answer above

Answer (score 0):

Today (end 2014) you have several options. You need a facebook developer ID however.

[This website made by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) allows you to embed pages in different ways (HTML5, IFrame etc) on your website.