# catching Error(or Exception) if url fails to load in iframe in angular 2(or 4)

Tags: html, angular

i have the following element in the angular 4 code

```
<iframe #originalUrl [hidden]="!showOriginalDoc" onError="onIframeError(event)"  
    [src]="originalUrl">
   <span *ngIf="originalUrl==='sss'">Original URL Not Available</span>
</iframe>
```

where originalUrl is dynamically assigned from the API response, some websites block by throwing an error : Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. I want to display a message with the URL in it after catching the above error, please tell anyone how to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a website doesn't permit iframe embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422300/checking-if-a-website-doesnt-permit-iframe-embed)

Comment: no it is not in angular 2+ context

Comment: Angular is built on the top of javascript, so any solution using plain/vanilla javascript is valid.

Comment: I tried this way "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422300/checking-if-a-website-doesnt-permit-iframe-embed" but am not able to see the 'x-frame-options' in the header in the code, but there is an error in the console ''Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'", how to get the headers?